# After installation self start Android application

Tags: android

Android app is downloaded from play store and finished installation.

After installation how to self start that application without user click.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, as of Android 3.1, to help prevent "drive-by malware".

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't. Since Android 3.1, applications [start off in the stopped state](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

This means they're not eligible for *any* broadcasts until the user manually starts the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when user upgrades your app from Google Play.

If it's ok for you then register your `BroadcastReeiver` on `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` data